# How to make the cursor visible when window is unfocused in LablGTK2?

Tags: gtk, ocaml

I am writing a text editor using LablGTK2 and I was wondering if it is possible, using a GSourceView2.source_view, to make the cursor visible even when the window does not have focus. I've searched for this answer, but I haven't found anything that addresses this question.

Comment: This appears to be a GTK in general problem.